# free a dynamically allocated array inside another dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

Say I had the following simple example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct x {
    int* p;
};

typedef struct y {
    x* foo;
}real;

void doSomething();

int main() {
    doSomething();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void doSomething() {
   real* tmp = (real*)malloc(sizeof(real));
   tmp->foo = (x*)malloc(sizeof(x));
   free(tmp->foo);
   free(tmp);
}
```

Is it necessary to free the pointer I allocated inside before I free the "outer" allocated memory?

would the second line take care of the first allocated memory...my assumption is no(it will still remain on the heap I assume and I would need to keep it this way).

Comment: Note that in `struct y`, you refer to a type `x` but, in C, that is not the type specified by `struct x`.  Only C++ defines the type `x` after you define `struct x`; C leaves the type `x` undefined until you use `typedef struct x x;`.  That means your code should not compile with a C compiler — but maybe you're using a C++ compiler to compile the code after all, despite the C tag.  (Maybe the compiler is the MS Visual Studio compiler, at that.)

Comment: you are correct....it's a c++ compiler in VS

Comment: @JonathanLeffler C++ tag  removed by  Yu Hao.

Comment: The answers are 'yes' and 'no'; you need to free the inner allocated memory before freeing the outer (because you can't refer to the inner pointer via the outer after you've freed the outer).

Comment: It gets tricky deciding what to do.  If it is C++ code, you shouldn't be using `malloc()` and `free()` — you use `new` and `delete` if you aren't using types that take care of memory allocation automatically.  If it is not C++ code, it doesn't compile.  If it is C++ code, the casts on the results from `malloc()` are necessary (assuming you use `malloc()` at all); if it is C, you don't need the casts, though they don't do much harm if you're careful.  Waaah!

Comment: `x* foo;`...this compiles?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding my two cents to elaborate on the *why* part.

Let's state two concepts first.

1. You need to `free()`*each* memory allocated by memory allocator function to avoid memory leak.
2. You need to pass the *exact* pointer returned by `malloc()` or family to `free()`. They do not have any *hierarchical*  information *stored* into them (Like, *"member of the structure"* kind, each allocation is individual).

So, to *reach* the *inner* pointer member `foo`, you must access (dereference) the outer pointer `tmp`.

Now, if you `free()` the outer pointer `tmp` first, afterwards, accessing that free-d memory is invalid invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, you have no way to reach the *inner* pointer to call `free()` on it. It remains allocated and contributes to memory leak.

That is why, you have to start freeing the memory *from inside out*.

Answer (score 0):

The first malloc will just allocate space for holding the members of `y`. Deleting it only deletes that allocated space. It has nothing to do with what you allocate afterwards. So yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: i was maybe thinking that free was smart enough to see if any of its members had more allocated memory...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple rule, every malloc call should have a corresponding free call, else consider the memory is not freed. The argument to free must be the value returned by corresponding malloc. Additionally, it is better to do a NULL check before passing the pointer to free.

In your example, `struct real` has `struct x` as it's member and `struct x` in turn has `int *p` as it's member. In your real code, you will also have to allocate memory for `p` and also free the memory when your usage is done.

Comment: Additionally, If there is a possibility that a given `p` can remain unallocated in your collection of `real` and `x`'s, you may want to protect your `free` with a check to insure `p` is not `NULL` (e.g. `if (p) free (p);`). (Jay, I know you know, this is for the questioner)

Comment: This answer does seem to imply that anything with regards to a needed `free` would be different if using C++ - It isn't.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin & tofro, Hope I have addressed your comments in my recent edit. Thanks for your comments. : )